# How to use bind a element created by a directive into a model in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to model an input element with a object in controller, but the element is not a element in html. I have a directive and inside that I'm making that element(`newElement` in following snippets). 
1.Directive:

```
panel.directive('ngCustomType', function ($compile) {
return {
    scope: {
        entity: '='
    },
 link: function (scope, elem, attrs){
    newElement = angular.element('<input type="text"/>');
    newElement.attr("ng-model", "entity.name");     // I also tried newElement.attr("ng-model", "currentEntity.name"); but it didn't work
    $compile(newElement)(scope);
    elem.append(newElement);
}
```

2.Controller:

```
$scope.currentEntity = {name: ""};
```

3.View:

```
<div ng-custom-type  entity="currentEntity"></div>
```

When I check created input element in generated html I have `ng-model='entity.name'`  in input element but it is not really modeled by my object, and when I change the input `currentEntity.name` doesn't change. How can I bind them together?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
newElement.attr("ng-model", "entity.name");
```